# OLAP Attribute Number Rounding?

Tags: sql-server-2008, olap

Is there a way to format things in the cube?

Some attributes are showing little errors for floats (1.00000000001) when I want to do something like "%.2f".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert(numeric(20,2), number)
```

and if is doesn't work properly this will:

```
convert(numeric(20,2), round(number, 2))
```

Comment: This is on the SQL server or is it part of the cube?